# AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployment error: InvalidParameterValue: Template does not have a numeric EvaluationPeriods setting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting an error when attempting to deploy an EB worker application using `.ebextensions`. I have two files in my `.ebextensions`:

options.config:

```yaml
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs:
    StreamLogs: true
    DeleteOnTerminate: true
    RetentionInDays: '7'
  
  aws:ec2:instances:
    InstanceTypes: t2.micro,t3.micro

  aws:autoscaling:trigger:
    EvaluationPeriods: '1'

  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    SecurityGroups: sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxx

  aws:autoscaling:asg:
    Cooldown: '60'
    MinSize: '0'
    MaxSize: '5'
  
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:
    Port: '2030'

  aws:elasticbeanstalk:sqsd:
    HttpPath: '/calculate'
    HttpConnections: '1'
    MaxRetries: '1'
```

worker-scaling.config

```yaml
Resources:
  AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmActions: []

  AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmActions: []

  QueueSizeAlarmHigh:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: "Scale up when queue has more than 1 message"
      Namespace: "AWS/SQS"
      MetricName: ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible
      Dimensions:
        - Name: QueueName
          Value:
            "Fn::Select":
              - 4
              - "Fn::Split":
                - '/'
                - "Fn::GetOptionSetting":
                    Namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:sqsd"
                    OptionName: "WorkerQueueURL"
      Statistic: Average
      Period: 60
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      Threshold: 1
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      AlarmActions:
        - Ref: AWSEBAutoScalingScaleUpPolicy

  QueueSizeAlarmLow:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: "Scale down when queue has less than 1 message"
      Namespace: "AWS/SQS"
      MetricName: ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible
      Dimensions:
        - Name: QueueName
          Value:
            "Fn::Select":
              - 4
              - "Fn::Split":
                - '/'
                - "Fn::GetOptionSetting":
                    Namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:sqsd"
                    OptionName: "WorkerQueueURL"
      Statistic: Average
      Period: 60
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      Threshold: 1
      ComparisonOperator: LessThanThreshold
      AlarmActions:
        - Ref: AWSEBAutoScalingScaleDownPolicy
```

I have been following this tutorial: https://elasticbeanstalkscaling.workshop.aws/04_scaleworkers.html

However, when deploying I receive the following error:

```
Failed to deploy application.
InvalidParameterValue: Template does not have a numeric EvaluationPeriods setting
```

I am trying to keep as much of the config as possible in the ebextensions so that the repo can be pushed to multiple environments and they will all act in the same way. As such, I have not touched anything but the bare-minimum default settings when creating the EB, as I understand that if you select settings upon creation they take precedence over the `options.config` settings.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you have empty `AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh` & `AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow` alarms? If you don't need them, delete them and that should solve the issue

Comment: They are empty to remove them as the defaults. I then create 2 new alarms that are based on an SQS queue size.

Comment: If I delete those entries, the default alarms of "NetworkIn" will remain.

Comment: What line is the error thrown on?

Comment: Try using `ActionsEnabled: false` instead of setting the `AlarmActions` - what does that give you?

Comment: Or it may be the `aws:autoscaling:trigger:` in your `options.config` - just throwing out ideas...

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Thanks for your suggestions - no luck yet sadly. Could it be something to do with how numeric values are set in the config? In some examples I see numbers enclosed in single quotes and elsewhere I see no quotes. I've tried both with no luck but maybe there is some other part of the config that requires this?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Is it possible to see where the error is? At the moment I just simply get the message - it doesn't refer to any line number or file

Comment: Did removing the entirety of `aws:autoscaling:trigger: EvaluationPeriods: '1'` yield a different error?

Comment: No errors when removing that part from options.config - so I guess that narrows it down to the worker-scaling.config. I've tried wrapping numbers with and without single quotes (as I see it done both ways in various examples) and still no luck yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well turns out the answer was simple but these errors from AWS did not make it obvious at all.

The instance type simply had to be changed to Load Balanced from Single Instance. This is obvious since the whole point of what we're doing here is to adjust how the scaling works - although my original logic was to try and keep as much config in the version controlled config file as possible. However, as it turns out, you cannot set the `EnvironmentType` via the config, so this is simply a step that should be performed at the start.

Hopefully this saves someone a good few hours in the future!